# Ошибка в Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Внезапно ни с того ни с сего при попытке обновить таблицу бд sql server начала появляться окно прекращена работа программы. Хоть вчера такого не было. Скринить ошибку я думаю бесполезно ибо там не пишет не кода ошибки, ни где возникла. Просто прекращена работа программы. Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: в виндовых событиях есть записи?

Comment: Прекращена работа Студии или вашей программы?

Comment: Полезный совет: чтобы не скринить диалоговые окна, достаточно просто нажать Ctrl+C (когда окно в фокусе) - текст с него будет скопирован в буфер обмена.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov прекращена работа программы Microsoft Visual Studio